# Java andorid RXJava2 post in service to Activity and have to times this same onNext

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

In service I post my event :

```
RxBus.getSubject().onNext(eventAddNoteAndRealize) ;
```

This is my RxBus :

```
public final class RxBus {

    private  static final BehaviorSubject<Object> behaviorSubject
            = BehaviorSubject.create();


    public synchronized static BehaviorSubject<Object> getSubject() {
        return behaviorSubject;
    }
}
```

And In my Activity I have this :

```
DisposableObserver<Object> disposable = RxBus.getSubject().
        subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Object>() {


            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) {
                if (o instanceof EventAddNoteAndRealize) {
                    Toast.makeText(NewMainActivity.this , "next", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    EventAddNoteAndRealize event = new EventAddNoteAndRealize(((EventAddNoteAndRealize) o).getNoteAndRealizeDAOList());
                    eventAddNoteAndRealize = event;
                    getRealizeAndNote((EventAddNoteAndRealize)o);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });
```

And a method onNext execute two times this same objects. I do not have idea what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are not emitting the same object 2 times because as i test your code it works good

```
    @Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    DisposableObserver<Object> disposable = RxBus.getSubject().
            subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Object>() {


                @Override
                public void onNext(Object o) {
                    System.out.println(o);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });

    Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(aLong -> {
                RxBus.getSubject().onNext(aLong);
               return aLong;
            }).subscribe();
}

}
 final class RxBus {

private  static final BehaviorSubject<Object> behaviorSubject
        = BehaviorSubject.create();


public synchronized static BehaviorSubject<Object> getSubject() {
    return behaviorSubject;
}
```

make sure that you are not emitting object to times my response is 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
.
.
.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185608/discussion-on-answer-by-ricard-kollcaku-java-andorid-rxjava2-post-in-service-to).